# What are some open source tools to check a software architecture's robustness?

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

I think it is a tough question but I want to verify the architecture of my software is robust enough.

I've plans to execute these tools on my code:

- [Gendarme](http://www.mono-project.com/Gendarme)
- [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [StyleCop](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis)
- Visual Studio's code metrics
- Visual Studio's code analysis

But I want some tools to check (among others):

- the relations between assembly's' dependencies
- too strong coupling between my objects
- and so forth.

In a word, I want **open source** tools to highlight any architectural glitches of my project.

I understand the best tool is an experienced architect, but even the best carpenter needs a good hammer ;)

Comment: Did you run Code Analysis and Code Metrics on your code through Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, but I forgot to put it in the list. I edit my post

Comment: Not free or open source, but did you look at nDepend?

Comment: I think one problem is that there is no definition for 'robust' there is only something that might be appropriate for what you're trying to do. For example, software cannot know how important extensiblity is to you (it might not be). Or how important it is to have low latency, or an audit trail. You can of course check against rules like "do not have more than 4 parameters to a method" but that doesn't test robustness, just compliance with rules of thumb.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The built-in Visual Studio tools are good, if you have the advanced editions.

You can also look at [nDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/), which is a tool to do static analysis and point out areas of your system that have a high number of dependencies or coupling, among many other features.  nDepend is a commercial product, but has a free academic license and is free to use if you are working on open-source development -- so this may or may not meet your criteria.

Be aware that all of these tools have a learning curve, and you are probably not going to have a "silver bullet" that tells you exactly what to change on your system, but they can be really useful to improve performance and maintainability, and reduce risk.

Comment: -1... none of the tools so far - including nDepend - deliver an architectural check as the OP asks for.

Comment: I think it depends on how you define "check" -- nDepend absolutely does provide detailed visual reports of the exact issues the poster mentioned, namely dependencies and tight coupling.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are asking a bit too much from the tools. Software architecture is a lot like the architecture of buildings, there is no right way to do it (there can be wrong ways) and to ask a tool to measure this is close to impossible.

There are a huge number of tools that can measure smaller aspects (comments, naming conventions, performance, etc) but you will not find a tool that can tell you whether you have architected the solution correctly.

Comment: +1. Sorry, there is no artificial intelligence - the moment you get into architecture reviews you need a brain and experience and the requirements to see whether your architecture is sensible. This is not toolable.

Comment: I'm not looking for the Holy Grail of architecture's maker/corrector but tools that tell me there's bad smell at some place. The final architectural decision will be mine ;)

Answer (score 1):

The tools you've enumerated so far are static code analysis tools that can help visualize some of the emergent architectural patterns, but won't be able to do much more than that. They are wonderful for helping reduce developer error, prove program correctness (to a degree), and tease out bad smells and good practices.

Yet, there are many dimensions to architecture that these won't measure. Scalability, performance, deployment footprint, uptime, runtime characteristics, etc.

Many of these tools simply don't know anything about the business context either. That's more of a measure of success.